# Color containers in array flutter

Tags: list, colors, flutter, containers, increment

Question updated apr 10:

Hi!
I'm still stuck and can't get this to work :(

I'm trying to make an app where the user will answer a total of 3 questions before he's navigated to a result-screen.
To show the progress of the questions there will be 3 colored containers in a row. The row will initally be for example blue but when the user answers correct - the container for that question will turn green, and if answer is incorrect the container will turn red.

I could really use some further help here.

Below I have made the code as simple as I can with different colors just to show the different items in the list.

Right now it works fine with the first question, but then it kind of stops.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'listing 4',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  int sum = 5;
  String userAnswer;
  String correction = "";

  List<Color> colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.amber, Colors.pink];

  submitPressed(int index) {
    if (userAnswer == sum.toString()) {
      setState(() {
        correction = sum.toString();
        colors[index] = Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      colors[index] = Colors.red;
    }
  }

  Widget myListBuilder() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 3,
      itemBuilder: buildContainer,
    );
  }

  Widget buildContainer(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 20.0,
        width: 15.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: colors[index], //this is the important line
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Listing 4'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: Text('Correct answer is 5',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              ),
               Container(
                width: 50.0,
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  autofocus: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    userAnswer = val;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  submitPressed(0);
                },
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildContainer(context, 0),
                  buildContainer(context, 1),
                  buildContainer(context, 2)
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try creating a list of colors that is the same length as the number of boxes you have. When you build a box in the `ListView` you set its colour to its position within the list. That way when you update the colour in the list for the specific box, it will only update the box that is using that position's color.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will try :)

Comment: Hmm... Pretty basic stuff maybe, but how is the best way of making a list and then let it change one color at a time? I was thinking like List<bool>correctionColor, where  defautColor = blue, after update: true = green and false = red.

Comment: I would make a `List<Color>` and then set them all to default. You would then edit the color within the list in order to change the colors.

Comment: Yup, good idea. I have that at the moment. I updated my question in the last part (some more code). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm stuck :(

Comment: How so? Would you like me to write a formal answer?

Comment: I don't really know why, but I cant really wrap my head around it. I feel it should be so simple, but still I'm totally stuck. Yes please, anything that can help me sort this out would be awsome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to assume a few things within this answer, so change them as necessary. The colours you are going to use are `Colors.blue` for the default color, `Colors.green` for correct, and `Colors.red` for incorrect.

You would first initialise a List of colors, all of which will be blue as that is the default color:

```dart
List<Color> colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.blue, Colors.blue ..... Colors.blue] 
//You will write Colors.blue ten times as there are 10 boxes.
```

I'm going to assume that you use a `ListView.builder` here, as you haven't specified it in your code example. You would build your `ListView` as such:

```dart
//Place this within your widget tree
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: buildContainer,
  itemCount: 10,
);
```

You will then need to modify your `buildContainer` method as the `itemBuilder` parameter requires a method to take `context` and `index` and output a widget, therefore:

```dart
Widget buildContainer(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Container(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 20.0,
        width: 15.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colors[index], //this is the important line
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

This will then create 10 boxes that each have gotten their colour from their position within the list of colors created earlier. Now you just have to change the color when they are finished. Using your code example:

```dart
if (userAnswer == widget.sum.toString()) {
  setState(() {
    correction = widget.sum.toString();
    //Here we will instead set the specific color in the array
    colors[index] = Colors.green;
  });
} else {
  correction = widget.sum.toString();
  colors[index] = Colors.red;
}
```

The only thing you need to do is make sure the function when you click next takes a variable which is the index of the questions, i.e. the question number you are on.

Comment: The code is totally updated for this question. The problem still remains tho :(